# Configuring umask in ProFTPD

Tags: ftp

My issue is that no matter what I put as umask in proftpd.conf, I still get same `-rw-r-----` permission for newly uploaded files. I've tried 0002 0002, 0022 0022 and 0066 0066 just to get some sort of change but nothing happens - no matter what the umask is the end result is the same.

ProFTPD version is 1.3.5rc3 and I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.

I've read through all the ProFTPD questions about umask but can't find answer that would work.

*EDIT*
Here's log:

`2015-02-09 13:02:34,506 (...): FTP session opened.
2015-02-09 13:02:34,549 (...): USER XXX: Login successful.
2015-02-09 13:02:34,773 (...): ROOT PRIVS: unable to seteuid(): Operation not permitted
2015-02-09 13:02:34,773 (...): ROOT PRIVS: unable to setegid(): Operation not permitted
2015-02-09 13:02:34,774 (...): RELINQUISH PRIVS: unable to seteuid(PR_ROOT_UID): Operation not permitted
2015-02-09 13:02:34,774 (...): FTP session closed.`

So there's obviously something going on with permissions. I'm running ProFTPD as root.

Comment: FTP or SFTP? What client are you using?

Comment: FTP, Filezilla.

Comment: It works just find for me with `Umask` directive in `.ftpaccess` file and FileZilla/FTP. How exactly are you setting umask? Also set debug logging in ProFTPD and inspect the log.

Comment: I've tried to set ```Umask``` in ```.ftpaccess``` as well and no effect.

Comment: What FTP client are you using for uploading the files?  Some FTP clients, for example, will issue a `SITE CHMOD` FTP command, after upload, to explicitly set the permissions on a file.  If your FTP client does this, it could explain why the `Umask` does not appear to be working.